# Div Not Expanding for Elements

Tags: css, html, background

I've got a new website for my production company in the works, and right now it's being rather fussy.

I have a main body element that contains a video and a sidebar div. These are set to float to the left and right, and they along with a header div are all contained inside one big "frame" div that is centered in the page. The outline goes something like this:

```
<frame>
    <header>
    </header>
    <main>
        <video>
            <vidframe> <- This is for keeping the iframe's aspect ratio (read it in some online tutorial)
                <iframe>
                </iframe>
            </vidframe>
        </video>
        <sidebar>
        </sidebar>
    </main>
</frame>
```

Now, the frame div has a white background, and this separates the content from my background image. However, the problem is that the main div, and by extension the frame div are not extending down past the header to contain the video and sidebar divs. You can view the problem [here on my website](http://papkeeproductions.com).

I'm assuming it's either something to do with the float properties or with the position properties, but I can't figure out what is wrong. Here is what my CSS looks like:

```
div.frame {
    width:70%;
    height:auto;
    background-color:#FFF;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    padding:0;
    box-shadow:0 0 20px 0 #000;
}
div.main {
}
div.video {
    margin-left:3.57%;
    margin-top:3.57%;
    width:57.14%;
    float:left;
}
div.vidframe {
    position:relative;
    padding-bottom:56.25%;
    height:0;
    overflow:hidden;
}
div.vidframe iframe {
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
div.sidebar {
    margin-right:3.57%;
    margin-top:3.57%;
    width:32.14%;
    float:right;
}
```

Again, this is all live [at my website.](http://papkeeproductions.com)

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to clear the floats. add `<div style="clear:both"></div>` before the closing tag of the div with the class main. after line 34 in your html

Comment: Thanks. Why exactly does this fix the problem? Do floating divs not count as part of a div's content?

Comment: @Patrick That's exactly what floating means -- it takes the element out of the layout and line calculations. Clearing floats sort of encapsulates all the floating stuff prior to the clear in an imaginary box that IS in the layout model.